# Edit element.style in HTML code in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

I would like to add a style to a banner in the Shopify-Code. (A padding and a backgroudn color)
This banner has no deticated css that only applies to these kind of banners (or i can not find it) so i have to edit the element.style.

Could you help me how to edit this?

[I attached an image with the changes i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnCa4.png)

I think this is the part of the code where the changes should be made:

```
{{ 'section-image-banner.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

{%- if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank -%}
  {%- style -%}
  @media screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}:not(.banner--mobile-bottom) .banner__content::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    #Banner-{{ section.id }}::before,
    #Banner-{{ section.id }} .banner__media::before {
      padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;
      content: '';
      display: block;
    }
  }
  {%- endstyle -%}
{%- endif -%}

{%- style -%}
  #Banner-{{ section.id }}::after {
    opacity: {{ section.settings.image_overlay_opacity | divided_by: 100.0 }};
  }
{%- endstyle -%}

<div id="Banner-{{ section.id }}" class="banner banner--content-align-{{ section.settings.desktop_content_alignment }} banner--content-align-mobile-{{ section.settings.mobile_content_alignment }} banner--{{ section.settings.image_height }}{% if section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile and section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner--stacked{% endif %}{% if section.settings.adapt_height_first_image and section.settings.image != blank %} banner--adapt{% endif %}{% if section.settings.show_text_below %} banner--mobile-bottom{%- endif -%}{% if section.settings.show_text_box == false %} banner--desktop-transparent{% endif %}">
  {%- if section.settings.image != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {%-liquid
        assign image_height = section.settings.image.width | divided_by: section.settings.image.aspect_ratio
        if section.settings.image_2 != blank
          assign image_class = "banner__media-image-half"
        endif
        if section.settings.image_2 != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile
          assign sizes = "(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw"
        elsif section.settings.image_2 != blank
          assign sizes = "50vw"
        else
          assign sizes = "100vw"
        endif
      -%}
      {{ section.settings.image | image_url: width: 1500 | image_tag:
        loading: 'lazy',
        width: section.settings.image.width,
        height: image_height,
        class: image_class,
        sizes: sizes,
        widths: '375, 550, 750, 1100, 1500, 1780, 2000, 3000, 3840',
        alt: section.settings.image.alt | escape
      }    </div>
  {%- elsif section.settings.image_2 == blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image == blank and section.settings.image_2 == blank %} placeholder{% endif %}{% if section.settings.image_2 != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {{ 'lifestyle-2' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if section.settings.image_2 != blank -%}
    <div class="banner__media media{% if section.settings.image != blank %} banner__media-half{% endif %}">
      {%-liquid
        assign image_height_2 = section.settings.image_2.width | divided_by: section.settings.image_2.aspect_ratio
        if section.settings.image != blank
          assign image_class_2 = "banner__media-image-half"
        endif
        if section.settings.image != blank and section.settings.stack_images_on_mobile
          assign sizes = "(min-width: 750px) 50vw, 100vw"
        elsif section.settings.image != blank
          assign sizes = "50vw"
        else
          assign sizes = "100vw"
        endif
      -%}
      {{ section.settings.image_2 | image_url: width: 1500 | image_tag:
        loading: 'lazy',
        width: section.settings.image_2.width,
        height: image_height_2,
        class: image_class_2,
        sizes: sizes,
        widths: '375, 550, 750, 1100, 1500, 1780, 2000, 3000, 3840',
        alt: section.settings.image_2.alt | escape
      }}
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  <div class="banner__content banner__content--{{ section.settings.desktop_content_position }} page-width">
    <div class="banner__box content-container content-container--full-width-mobile color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }} gradient">
      {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
        {%- case block.type -%}
          {%- when 'heading' -%}
            <h2 class="banner__heading {{ block.settings.heading_size }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.heading | escape }}</span>
            </h2>
          {%- when 'text' -%}
            <div class="banner__text {{ block.settings.text_style }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              <span>{{ block.settings.text | escape }}</span>
            </div>
          {%- when 'buttons' -%}
            <div class="banner__buttons{% if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank and block.settings.button_label_2 != blank %} banner__buttons--multiple{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_1 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_1 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_1 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_1 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_1 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if block.settings.button_label_2 != blank -%}
                <a{% if block.settings.button_link_2 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_2 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_2 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_2 | escape }}</a>
              {%- endif -%}

            </div>
        {%- endcase -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.image-banner.name",
  "tag": "section",
  "class": "section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "image_2",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_2.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "image_overlay_opacity",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 100,
      "step": 10,
      "unit": "%",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_overlay_opacity.label",
      "default": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "image_height",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "small",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "medium",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "large",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "medium",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.image_height.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "adapt_height_first_image",
      "default": false,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.adapt_height_first_image.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.adapt_height_first_image.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "desktop_content_position",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "top-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "top-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "top-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__3.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__4.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__5.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "middle-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__6.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__7.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__8.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "bottom-right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.options__9.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "middle-center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_position.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_text_box",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.show_text_box.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "desktop_content_alignment",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.desktop_content_alignment.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "color_scheme",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "accent-1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.accent_1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "accent-2",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.accent_2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "background-1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.background_1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "background-2",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.background_2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "inverse",
          "label": "t:sections.all.colors.inverse.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "background-1",
      "label": "t:sections.all.colors.label",
      "info": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.color_scheme.info"
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.header.content"
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "mobile_content_alignment",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__1.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__2.label"
        },
        {
          "value": "right",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.options__3.label"
        }
      ],
      "default": "center",
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.mobile_content_alignment.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "stack_images_on_mobile",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.stack_images_on_mobile.label"
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_text_below",
      "default": true,
      "label": "t:sections.image-banner.settings.show_text_below.label"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "heading",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.heading.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "heading",
          "default": "Image banner",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.heading.settings.heading.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "heading_size",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "h2",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h1",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "h0",
              "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "h1",
          "label": "t:sections.all.heading_size.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "text",
          "default": "Give customers details about the banner image(s) or content on the template.",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_style",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "body",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__1.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "subtitle",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__2.label"
            },
            {
              "value": "caption-with-letter-spacing",
              "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.options__3.label"
            }
          ],
          "default": "body",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.text.settings.text_style.label"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "buttons",
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.name",
      "limit": 1,
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label_1",
          "default": "Button label",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_1.label",
          "info": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_1.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "button_link_1",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_link_1.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "button_style_secondary_1",
          "default": false,
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_style_secondary_1.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label_2",
          "default": "Button label",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_2.label",
          "info": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_label_2.info"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "button_link_2",
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_link_2.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "checkbox",
          "id": "button_style_secondary_2",
          "default": false,
          "label": "t:sections.image-banner.blocks.buttons.settings.button_style_secondary_2.label"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.image-banner.presets.name",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "heading"
        },
        {
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "type": "buttons"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

I attached an image with the changes i want to make.
Basically i addeted

```
padding: 0 5rem;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

to the element.style in google Chrome DevTool

Comment: Not sure what makes you think this would need inline styles. Why don't you use the same selector, that currently applies the given padding and background to the element already? As long as your custom CSS loads after the default one, a selector with the same specificity would "win" already. And if that's not the case, increase the specificity of your own selector, for example by replacing the `*` with the specific element name `img`.

Comment: Hey, so maybe it is better to explain my main problem:
 The banner at the end of this page should be the same With as the other elements of the page.  so i played a bit with the css to see wht kind of changes do the work. I could not edit a css. file that is existing because all the time it affected some other parts of the website. 

Maybe you would be so nice to take a look:  
Website is: https://elevant.berlin/
Image of the banner: https://prnt.sc/y-pt8IkPCGq_